# Lots of noise in the microphone amplifier circuit when idle

Tags: amplifier, bjt, microphone, speakers

I come again to get help from the experts.

I am using this BJT transistor in the circuit.

http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N3904.pdf

Here is the microphone that I am hooking up in the circuit.

It's an electret condenser microphone from digikey.

http://www.cui.com/product/resource/cma-4544pf-w.pdf

Here is my design

I am following the tutorial from this link to build the amplifier. It's exactly the same circuit but with different values to make it work with microcontroller. For that, I have used the supply voltage of 5V instead of 9V as in the tutorial. I have also tweaked the values of resistors to make the correct biased voltage.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Br3uOM0IVjc

[image]

The problem is that I get a lot of noise. I checked with oscillosope and it is biased correctly, i.e., midway between the 5V. But you can see a very noisy signal. I hooked the circuit to a computer speaker and you can hear the noise after you hook up the circuit. The output works correctly though, i.e, when you play a sound in the microphone you can hear clearly in the speaker but during idle there is a noise that is audible.

What is the reason of this noise and how to minimize it while the microphone is sitting idle? Thank you for the help.

Comment: What are you powering the circuit from? Have you added a decoupling capacitor across the circuit?

Comment: i am powering the circuit directly from 5v arduino pins. is that a problem?

Comment: could be - I'd be looking to power a circuit from the power supply rather than a pin output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noise is very unlikely to be coming from any of the components in the circuit. The biggest culprit is likely to be the power supply. Add a 22uF and 0.1 uF (helps with high frequencies) capacitor and a 100 ohm resistor that feed the electret part of the circuit and a 22uF across the 5V supply.
[image]

Comment: worth giving +1 point.

Comment: thanks a lot JIm Dearden, adding a cap in parallel to the power supply definately reduced the noise a lot. But 47 uF doesn't seem enough. I put one big 470 uF cap and it reduced the noise a lot. i am testing other suggestions you provided.

Comment: @user734861 you may have to experiment with values but at least you have a strategy for reducing/eliminating the source of the noise.

Comment: holy cow! thanks a lot jim that reduced all the noise. your the boss.

Comment: out of curiosity what does adding 100 ohm at the point you specified achieve?

Comment: User734861: It attenuates the AC ripple noise. Acts as a low low pass filter. Even lower than 50Hz.

Comment: thanks but i still dont see how the resistor makes it a low pass filter.